# subscript out of bounds error with two for loops inside the function

Tags: r, function, for-loop, matrix, dimension

I am trying to use a two dimension matrix to produce a two dimension matrix result where
the number of rows and number of columns are determined in a new way everytime I change the values in the function which determines the number of rows and number of columns accordingly.
The function that I would like to ask and resolve the "subscript out of bounds" problem is the following:

```
 HRC <- function(n,b,c)
 { 
 R=matrix( ,nrow = n*b, ncol = c)
 R[0,]=133
 for (j in 1:c)
 {
 r=rnorm(n*b)
 for (i in 1:n*b){
 R[i+1,j]=R[i,j]+3*b/r[i]
 }
 }
 return(R)
 }

 HRC(10,1,3)
```

The error message that I get is the following:

```
 Error in R[i + 1, j] = R[i, j] + 3 * b/r[i] : subscript out of bounds
```

I wonder how I can resolve this problem. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you loop from row `b` to row `n*b` (with stride `b`, due to the precedence of `*` and `:`) and then index to one greater, so you attempt to index row `n*b + 1` of `R`, which is out of bounds.

`R[0,]<-` will cause incorrect results but not elicit an error from R.

I find the code easier to read if you loop from `2` to `n*b`, the number of rows, and write the formula in terms of creating row `i` from row `i-1` (rather than creating row `i+1` from row `i`).

In addition, you can drop one loop dimension by vectorizing the operations over the rows:

```
HRC <- function(n, b, c) { 
  R <- matrix(NA, nrow = n*b, ncol = c)
  R[1,] <- 133

  r <- matrix(rnorm(n*b*c), ncol=c)
  for (i in 2:(n*b)){
    R[i,] <- R[i-1,] + 3*b/r[i-1,]
  }

  return(R)
}


HRC(10,1,3)
```

Here, the same number of random samples are taken with `rnorm` but they are formed as a matrix, and used in the same order as used in the question.  Note that not all of the random values are actually used in the computation.

If you set a random seed and then run this function, and the function in @flodel's answer, you will get identical results.  His answer is also correct.

Comment: Thank you very much especially for making a very clear clarification about the indexing and the articulated explaination! I was really a huge help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

R's indexing starts at `1`, not `0`.

You also have to be careful with the operators precedence rules: the `:` operator has higher precedence than `*`. See `?Syntax`.

This should work:

```
HRC <- function(n, b, c) { 
  R <- matrix(NA, nrow = n*b, ncol = c)
  R[1,]=133
  for (j in 1:c) {
    r = rnorm(n*b)
    for (i in 1:(n*b-1)){
      R[i+1,j] = R[i,j] + 3*b/r[i]
    }
  }
  return(R)
}

HRC(10,1,3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It was really a huge help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making three mistakes:

First: You are messing up the row count on the index. It should be `1:(n*b)` and not `1:n*b`.

Second: In R, indexing starts at 1. So `R[0,]`  should be replaced by `R[1,]`.

Third: You are running the loops in the right bounds `1:c` and `1:(n:b)`, but you are probably not keeping track of the indices.

Try this:

```
set.seed(100)
HRC <- function(n, b, c) { 
  R <- matrix(0, nrow = n*b, ncol = c)
  R[1,] <- 133
  for (j in 1:c) {
    r <- rnorm(n*b)
    for (i in 2:(n*b)){
      R[i,j] <- R[i-1,j] + 3*b/r[i-1]
    }
  }
  return(R)
}

HRC(10,1,3)
```

Lastly, I would like to warn you about interchangeable use of the assignment operators. See [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/assignment-operators-in-r-%E2%80%98%E2%80%99-vs-%E2%80%98-%E2%80%99/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for making it more clear about it! I really do appreciate it! Thank you so much!